# Portable Internet Explorer 10 application?

Tags: internet-explorer-10, portable-apps

Is there a portable IE 10 version?

Perhaps a portable package that runs virtualized. Currently I am running Win8 with IE 10 inside a VW, which eats up much more resources than I would like.

I require IE 10 for compatibility testing of web projects.

Thanks.

Comment: Not that I'm aware of, other browsers yes, but not IE.

Answer (score 3):

You can try [Maxthon portable](http://portableapps.com/apps/internet/maxthon_portable) from [Portable Apps](http://portableapps.com/). This browser can use IE rendering engine, among others.

Comment: But does come with the IE10 Engine?

Answer (score 0):

It has its limitations, but [IETester](http://www.my-debugbar.com/wiki/IETester/HomePage) might help.

Comment: are the requirements an installed version of IE?

Comment: I haven't tried it yet, but I assume [as per this page](http://www.my-debugbar.com/wiki/IETester/IE10Preview) that copying the files from any working installation of IE 10 should work.